# SSH doesn't prompt for host authenticity, when connecting through jump-host first time

Tags: networking, command-line, ssh, authentication, rsa

There is a jump host, called via ProxyCommand, to access some servers. In the *.ssh/config* file there is a `Host` definition for each server and the command for the jumphost (with `%r` and `%h` coming from the Host configuration) :

```
Host myserver
    Hostname myserver.mydomain.net
    User technic
    port 22
    ProxyCommand ssh -x -p 22 jumpuser@jumphost ssh -6 -p 22 -x %r@%h "nc localhost %p"
```

Accessing the *jumphost* and **then** issuing the `ssh <host>` command works and prompt me to confirm the connection.
Then the following connections **work fine** even via *jumphost*.

If I instead try to connect **directly** via *jumphost* I get **no prompt for authenticity** confirmation and I just get a

> key_load_public: No such file or directory
>   Host key verification failed.

I use the following versions: *OpenSSH_6.9p1* and *LibreSSL 2.1.8*.

Do I need to first make a manual connection (manual connection to jumphost + manual connection to server) to each server, in order to have them work correctly afterwards?

Or *is there some setting for prompting me to confirm the connection **even at the first connection via jumphost**?* (without upgrading OpenSSH)

Comment: What jumphost method are you using, exactly?

Comment: `ProxyCommand ssh -x -p 22 jumpuser@jumphost ssh -6 -p 22 -x %r@%h "nc localhost %p"` (with %r and %h coming from the `Host` configuration)

Comment: Please update your question with this information. // Why not use `-J`? No need to make this work manually.

Comment: Updated with it. There is no `-J` option in my *ssh*. What does it do? And how can I make it work without that option? (assuming it is possible to skip the initial step I wrote about above)

Comment: I use *OpenSSH_6.9p1, LibreSSL 2.1.8*. I cannot find the option you mentioned [in the manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh).

Comment: [Found the `-J` option](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh) but my version doesn't support `ProxyJump`; I'd like to stick to the use of `ProxyCommand`.

Comment: I am not sure; that's how it set up in the whole company. Everybody uses it correctly like that. Not sure if the double connection was intended to make things more secure or more explicit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not connecting "directly". With your current configuration, you are actually making *two* SSH connections to the destination host. One SSH client runs on the jumphost, another runs on your local machine (talking to the destination through the former), and the error message is produced by the latter.

Your local client still works the same as before, but the remote (jumphost) client is run in non-interactive mode – it has no pseudoterminal, and even if it did, all its input/output is attached to your local client's "network side". So there is no way the remote client can produce a visible prompt (it would be misinterpreted by your local client as malformed SSH traffic) nor receive the confirmation input.

You can avoid this only by removing the second (redundant) connection *completely*, and simplifying your ProxyCommand to one of:

```
ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p jumpuser@jumphost

ProxyCommand ssh -x jumpuser@jumphost "nc -6 %h %p"

ProxyCommand ssh -x jumpuser@jumphost "socat stdio tcp6:%h:%p"

ProxyCommand ssh -x jumpuser@jumphost "(cat <&\$fd & cat >&\$fd) {fd}<>/dev/tcp/%h/%p"
```

Of these methods, prefer *ssh -W* if available, use *nc/ncat/socat* otherwise, try the *cat $fd* hack as last resort. (If the jumphost forbids *ssh -W* and has no *nc* nor *ncat* nor *socat*, try to talk with your IT team about why they're deliberately making it harder to use the jumphost properly.)

Comment: I will ask it for sure; ...when they will be back from holidays 

Comment: Perfect deductions. I tried the second example and it works flawlessly, **and** not even asking me anymore to confirm the authenticity! (I guess because the *jumphost* already verified it when connecting to other servers). Thank you! 

Comment: No; in all of these examples, the SSH protocol runs directly between your client and the final destination, and the jumphost is not involved in the verification at all – it only carries the data across. (This is practically identical to "TCP forwarding" using `ssh -L`.)